# How to replace all the whitespaces in a string if the whitespaces are surrounded by quotes in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, replace

I have a list l.

```py
l = ["This is","'the first 'string","and 'it is 'good"]
```

I want to replace all the whitespaces with "|space|" in strings that are within 's.

```
print (l)
# ["This is","'the|space|first|space|'string","and 'it|space|is|space|'good"]
```

I can't use a for loop inside a for loop and directly use .replace() as strings are not mutable

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

I have seen the below questions and none of them have helped me.

> Replacing string element in for loop Python (3 answers)
>
> Running replace() method in a for loop? (3 answers)
>
> Replace strings using List Comprehensions (7 answers)

I have considered using re.sub but can't think of a suitable regular expression that does the job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure regex isn't going to work in this situation. I think it would be easier to do something like split the string using the quotation marks as delimiters then the a string substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> def replace_spaces(str) :
...     parts = str.split("'")
...     for i in range(1,len(parts),2) :
...         parts[i] = parts[i].replace(' ', '|')
...     return "'".join( parts )
... 
>>> [replace_spaces(s) for s in l]
['This is', "'the|first|'string", "and 'it|is|'good"]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution! I can't believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved your replacing problem with regex. You might have to polish the given code snippet a bit more to suit your need.

If I understood the question correctly, the trick was to use a regular expression to find the right space to be replaced.

```
match = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'", k) #here k is an element in list.
```

Placing skeleton code for your reference:

```
import re

l = ["This is","'the first 'string","and 'it is 'good"]

#declare output

for k in l:
    match = re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'", k)
    if not match:
        #append k itself to your output
    else:
        p = (str(match).replace(' ', '|space|'))
        #append p to your output
```

I haven't tested it yet, but it should work. Let me know if you face any issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex text-munging` :

```
import re

l = ["This is","'the first 'string","and 'it is 'good"]

def repl(m):
  return m.group(0).replace(r' ', '|space|')

l_new = []
for item in l:
  quote_str = r"'.+'"
  l_new.append(re.sub(quote_str, repl, item))


print(l_new)
```

Output:

```
['This is', "'the|space|first|space|'string", "and 'it|space|is|space|'g
ood"]
```

Full logic is basically:

1. Loop through elements of `l`.
2. Find the `string between single quotes`. Pass that to `repl` function.
3. `repl` function I'm using simple `replace` to replace `spaces with |space|` .

Reference for text-munging => https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#text-munging